# Getting respondent names and email addresses in SurveyMonkey's API v3

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm upgrading my application from SurveyMonkey's API v2 to v3 and using the [liogi/surveymonkey-api-v3](https://github.com/liogi/surveymonkey-api-v3) library to wrap around my API calls and am not sure if I'm understanding how respondent info is being handled now.

The v2 endpoint [`POST /surveys/get_respondent_list`](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/methods/get_respondent_list/) would return `data.respondents[_].email`, `.first_name`, and `.last_name`, but [its v3 equivalent](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses) doesn't.

**Is it the case that with the API v3, this data can *only* be pulled from `pages[_].questions[_].answers[_].text`?**

I hope not, because that makes pulling respondent names and email addresses *way* more complicated and seemingly necessitates knowing the question IDs that correspond to the correct fields for every survey. Am I misinterpreting the API, or has that "get respondent's email address" feature been gutted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `email`, `first_name`, and `last_name` are now all in the contact data in the `metadata` field provided in the response body when [fetching a response](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses-id).

So a request like:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/<response_id>
```

will return something like this in the body:

```
{
    ...
    "metadata": {
       "contact": {
         "first_name": {
           "type": "string",
           "value": "Test"
         },
         "last_name": {
           "type": "string",
           "value": "Example"
         },
         "email": {
           "type": "string",
           "value": "test@example.com"
         }
       }
     }
    ...
}
```

Those 3 fields will also show up in the same place for the [bulk responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-bulk) endpoint.

Comment: Ah, so this is only available for email collectors and not weblink collectors.